How to proof Elgamal use simulator based on DDH and CDH problem？
How to proof Elgamal using simulator based on DDH and CDH problem？
I know the game-based method.
Is there some paper to ref？

What do you want to prove about ElGamal? What functionality do you want to simulate?
